# How to express all group elements in terms of generators in GAP

Tags: permutations, gap

I have a permutation group given in terms of its generators, such as

```
G := Group((2, 3), (1, 4), (1, 3)(2, 4));
```

I can iterate through the group and get all elements in cycle form. How can I get each element in terms of the generators? I imagine GAP has these expressions once it generates each element or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 39.5 of the GAP manual, "Expressing Elements as Words in Generators":

http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7E19F92284F6684E

describes the two ways how this can be done: `Factorization` guarantees a word of minimum length (but is more memory/time intensive). `PreImagesRepresentative`, when applied to `EpimorphismFromFreeGroup`, is faster but does not attempt to obtain minimum length.

Comment: Your solution is interesting, but since I create the group given generators, for GAP to compute all group elements it has to use the generators right? So in a sense I am recomputing stuff or not?

Comment: If you want a word expression for all elements run through the group elements and use `Factorization` -- Memory will become a problem far before runtime, even though you are doing some recomputation.

Comment: Doing that makes me want to die, but all right. :)