# Generating specific elements in $GL_2(\bf F_3)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields

$SL_2(\bf F_3)$ is generated by
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1\ 1 \\ 0\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$
and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
1\ 0 \\ 1\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$.

I think $GL_2(\bf F_3)$ is generated minimally by $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$

I am interested in generating these three elements:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0\ 2 \\ 1\ 1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1\ 0 \\ 1\ 1
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1\ 2 \\ 1\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
each have absolute value of determinant $1$. How can I use the generators to generate these elements? Is there a systematic procedure?

Comment: $SL_2$ has index $2$ here, so $GL_2$ is generated by any set of generators of $SL_2$ together with any matrix of determinant $-1$. A nice one to take is $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$.

Comment: Thank you. So \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix} suffices as additional generator. So do we need three generators?

Comment: @Turbo you have to be able to generate the entire special linear group then add one with a negative determinant. Note that there is a homomorphism from $GL_2(F_3) \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ which has two cosets that explains why this is sufficient.

Comment: Groupprops claims that two generators suffices (https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_linear_group:GL(2,3) ) but doesn't give a presentation with two generators (that I can find, anyway). Maybe GAP can do the calculation, I don't know.

Comment: GAP says $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 2& 0\end{bmatrix}$ do generate.

Comment: As to OP's last question, please check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1962430/58401) for two solutions in GAP.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying a matrix with $A$ and $B$ gives you all possible row and column operations, so by row/column reduction you have an algorithm for writing any matrix of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ as a product of $A$'s and $B$'s.

This works for $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for any prime $p$ actually.

Anyway, if you can write $A$ and $B$ using $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 2\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, you also have an algorithm for writing matrices of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ as products of $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 2\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.